# PHP How do I default to a specific value if none of the retreived ones via $_POST is valid?

Tags: php

I am a newbie so please excuse my dumb question, but I had a hard time finding an answer on g. I send a dropdown form data to a PHP script.
The dropdown has values A,B,C,D. I would like to default to A if anything other than A,B,C,D has been sent by the client. Same for another dropdown which uses numbers (this later on used for results per site), whereas I would like to reject high numbers above 100 and values which are not even a number (actually malicious requests).

How is this done?I would try for non-numeric stuff

```
$postvalue = htmlentities($postvalue, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
if($postvalue != "A" || "B" || "C" || "D"){
  $postvalue = "A";
}
```

and for numeric stuff

```
$postvalue = htmlentities($postvalue, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
if(!isnumeric($postvalue) OR $postvalue >= 100){
      $postvalue = 1;
    }
```

but I am not sure if this is correct/safe.

Comment: Why you are using `htmlentities` instead of `$_POST`? and `if($postvalue != "A" || "B" || "C" || "D")` should be `if ($postvalue != "A" && $postvalue != "B" && $postvalue != "C" && $postvalue != "D")`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to add validation, try this -

```
$acceptedVal = ['A','B','C','D'];
$postvalue = htmlentities($postvalue, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
if(!in_array($postvalue,$acceptedVal)){
  $postvalue = "A";
}
```